# Run Microsoft Recommenders library in Google Colab

Tags: dependencies, modulenotfounderror, recommendation-engine

How to install and run Microsoft recommenders library in google colab. I tried but I got an  error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Microsoft Recommender link https://github.com/microsoft/recommenders

I try these two commands to install Microsoft recommenders

```
!pip install --upgrade pip
!pip install recommenders
```

but when I import recommenders I got the following error attached in the screenshot [image]

Answer (score 0):

It works for me simply install the lib using the following command line

```
!pip install recommenders[examples]
```

add the following cell to choose tf1 is the code require tensorflow1.

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
```

[Colab Example Cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aj0Mr.png)

Answer (score 0):

when i was installing recommenders, module using `!pip install recommenders`  faced some errors related to setup of cornac, lightfm and scikit-sc.

I was able to resolve errors using below commands (I was using anaconda and python 3.7)

a. For cornac error

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install cornac==1.11.0
```

b. For lightfm and scikit-sc error

```
conda install -c conda-forge lightfm
conda config --add channels conda-forge
```

[
Let me know if this helps you :)
]